# Can I export Channel Images data to Grid?

Tags: grid, channel-images

I set up a site with Channel Images, but now the client wants more information to go with each image than is really possible with Channel Images, so I'm thinking of making it a Grid.

The question: is there any (easy) to export the data from my Channel Images field to Grid? I'm not really a MySQL person, by the way....

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method I use for similar scenarios.

The first step would be to get your Channel Images data into a CSV or XML document. To do that create a template to output the data you need to export into your grid field, then call the template in a browser window. If you choose CSV you can copy the data and save as a .csv file, or my preferred method is to use XML which you can just do save page to save the complete XML file (works in Firefox, other browser may be flaky displaying XML!).

To import your data into the grid field using http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab is handy!

Comment: Thanks! I'll let you know if this works out if it turns out that I need to do this. Looks like a good solution!